# How to get access to the Main Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is there a way to get a reference to the Main UI thread in Windows Forms from another worker thread?

Something like this:

```
public void FormLoad()//we are in Main UI Thread
    {
        Thread backThread = new Thread(DoWork);
        backThread.Start();

    }
    public void DoWork()
    {
        //get Main Thread instance
        //do some work
    }
```

UPDATE

I`m interested if there is some static property or class to get reference to main thread like Thread.CurrentThread for getting current thread.

Comment: What do you mean by "Get an instance of a thread"? Do you want to invoke a method in the Main Thread from a another thread?

Comment: @steavy why do you need to access the main thread? To change some property of a control?

Comment: Normally you would just send the required information to the thread.  What have you tried?

Comment: Sound's like [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) or passing the instance to the new class.

Comment: I need to know the state of MainThread. I need to know in back thread what is Main thread doing at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

```
Thread MainThread=null;//for reference
public void FormLoad()//we are in Main UI Thread
    {
        MainThread=Thread.CurrentThread;//main thread reference
        Thread backThread = new Thread(DoWork);
        backThread.Start();

    }
    public void DoWork()
    {
        //get Main Thread instance
        //do some work
    }
```

This should work!!!

Comment: Yes, of course, this should work. But isn`t there some static property or so, so I shouldn`t explicitly store the reference in FormLoad?

Comment: Try with dispatcher thread that should be the UI thread or main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always use ParameterizedThreadStart to start a thread and send parameters to it, since it's an object, you could pass a reference to the calling thread.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the `Thread` instance won't help, as that doesn't allow you to do anything useful. What you presumably want is to be able to get the main thread to *do something* (like: update itself).

In windows forms, you should have a sync-context; simply access `SynchronizationContext.Current`, and should should be able to use `Post` or `Send` to pass work to the main thread.

Alternatively, if that doesn't work (the ambient sync-context is `null`): pass any control/form to your worker; it can then call `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` to pass work to the main thread.

---

An alternative approach is to expose an event that you Invoke, have the UI listen to that event, and have the UI deal with switching back to the main thread, by calling `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` upon itself (when handling the event).